# mobile Css & Desktop Css set-up

Tags: css, mobile, web, desktop

I Set up A Desktop & mobile Css, I put the Desktop on index.html and the mobile on m.index.html but the Desktop is coming up on both Desktop/laptop and mobile.How can I get the mobile to work

Comment: How are you including the css?

Comment: and are you sure you are actually hitting the m.index.html?

Comment: When I load m.index.html im seeing mobile.css and reset.css
When I load index.html im seeing desktop.css and reset.css

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I'm using chrome to view sources...

Comment: you should add meta viewport tag to your mobile page: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: @SethMcClaine yeah I don't know how to put it together, that's where I get losted, the idea I got from http//lorde.co.nz

Comment: @nevermind so just add that code to the mobile.css?

Comment: @user3208769, no, in your html source for mobile page, inside head.

Comment: Still coming up desktop on mobie @nevermind

Comment: @user3208769, strange, i see mobile version on my android... try to clear cache...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate html and css files.

Add a viewport meta tag as [Seth McClaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2418295/seth-mcclaine) suggested into `<head>` element of your html, and use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for separate css for tablet/mobile :-)- kind of like this:

```
// main css
.foo {
  width: 1000px;
}

// Mobile:
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .foo {
     width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Comment: // desktop css
.foo {
  width: 1000px;
}

// Mobile .css:
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .foo {
     width: 500px;
  }
}